# How to identify physical disks in Linux RAID

Tags: usb, raid, software-raid

Is there a way of reliably being able to tell which physical drive in a RAID relates to the software device name given to it by the OS?

I have a RAID5 array of consumer-grade USB disks (and one spare) on a hub attached to a PC. This serves as a cheap NAS.

Each device is identified in `/proc/mdstat` by its device name (eg `sdb`, `sdc`).

From what I can tell, Linux device names are dependent on the order in which the hardware is read at boot. So I shouldn't for example put a sticker on each drive with those device names on them, because `sdc` today might be `sdb` in the future.

In the event of a failure, I could test the current device name mapping by stopping the RAID and then looking at `dmesg -W` as I remove each one by one until I remove the failed device by process of elimination. But is there a better way?

I see that I can't label RAID members individually - they all have to share the name of the array: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/persistent_block_device_naming#by-label

I have looked at `ledctl` but that does not work with consumer drives: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ledctl

Comment: You could identify the underlying disks by their individual UUID's.  You could even map these to drive names in udev (but the UUIDs will work between systems, the dev ID mapping wont - unless you replicate the mapping.

Comment: @davidgo So with `blkid` you mean? But I still have the problem of working out which *physical* disk relates to which UUID though. So if I run `blkid /dev/sdb1`, how do I know which physical drive that refers to?

Comment: Assuming the disk are all same make/model Can you shut down the array (maybe by rebooting without the USB installed) then individually plug each device in while watching  the system log, and use blkid on each device name as appropriate?  (If drives are different or have serial nos written on them you can use smartctl to identify the make/model)

Comment: @davidgo Yes, that's basically what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lsblk -S` to map each device to the disk's serial number (or WWN if you add `-o +wwn`).

The USB hub paths displayed by `lsusb.py -ci` or `udevadm info /dev/sdd | grep ID_PATH=` should have a fixed mapping to the physical USB ports, e.g. on my server "1-1.1" and "1-1.2" are wired to the front panel ports. The order of ports on an external hub might not always be obvious but it should still remain static once you figure it out.

Alternative to LEDs: The `scsi_start`/`scsi_stop` scripts from sg3_utils can make HDDs spin up or spin down on demand (without actually disconnecting them). If the array is idle, stop all disks and spin them up one-by-one until you've matched all enclosures to the HDD serial numbers.

Comment: Can you explain how to get `lsusb.py` - it doesn't seem to be in my path (but is it part of `lsusb`?)

Comment: It's from the same "usbutils" source as lsusb, yes, although some distributions don't install it – probably to avoid a dependency on Python? You could get it [from GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gregkh/usbutils/master/lsusb.py.in) and replace `@usbids@` with the correct path (like `/usr/share/misc/usb.ids`).

Comment: Also, how do I determine the order of the ports on the hub? This seems to be a version of the same problem: how can reliably know whether a Toshiba model MQ01UBD050 is `/dev/sdf`, and how can I determine which port is 1-1.6?

Comment: Trial and error for the first time, then you write the serial numbers on stickers, or the port numbers on your hub with a marker?

Comment: I see - although I think I could achieve the same thing with `dmesg` as I described in my question. So get a list of UUIDs with `blkid /dev/sdX` then remove each drive from the hub while looking at `dmesg` for the disconnect messages and writing the UUID onto a sticker to slap on the drive I've just removed?

Comment: Yes, except the disks will probably have the same UUID (of both the filesystem and the mdraid array), while WWNs and serial numbers are more permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer, but have since found out that using the lsblk `UUID_SUB` value it NOT a solution. A recent disk failure event has shown me `UUID_SUB` doesn't seem to be attached to the disk partition's superblock as I first thought.

I am therefore gutting my original answer and will leave it to others to vote to delete it.

To date, the only proven answer to the question is to use bare disks that have their serial numbers visible on the drive casing itself and not on an outer enclosure which may well be different. Then use `lsbk -S` to work out which physical drive to deal with in the even of failure.

Comment: You should be able to read out actual serial numbers using smartctl -a, regardless of whether the drive is enterprise or consumer. Works for me at least. And another tip: I keep a list of HDDs (serial #, purchase date, mfg date, vendor etc etc etc) and label them on both ends so I can both doublecheck which drive to replace, and more easily find the physical drive in the case.

Comment: Yes, but I have noticed that the serial numbers displayed by smartctl (and other utils) do not appear on the casings of some drives so it's not a reliable method of identification.

Comment: Can you share which drive models do not show correct serials? I've gone through a large number of drives from different manufacturers over the decades, and I've never seen the serial number not match what's on the sticker. Are those refurbished and wrongly (re)labeled perhaps?

Comment: @MiG for example, I have two of these, https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B091FS79T8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1  one which smartctl reports as a Seagate while the other is a Toshiba. But the plastic cases have serials that match neither :-)  I'm getting what I pay for.

Comment: Ah, these are OEM drives integrated into a different product, that's a very different case. The serial number on the case is of the case itself (or if sold as a unit, the whole product). There will *also* be a serial number on the HDD itself inside of that, which will match what you read with smartctl.